# DAG giving error now but no there was no error 2-3 days earlier

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have created a DAG and passed a sql file which has many queries and it got triggered successfully for 2-3 days and when I triggered today, it's getting failed but I have not changed anything.I am unable to understand what's the issue. Can someone please help me and also please let me know how I can schedule my DAG at 3 am PST daily. My sql file is :-

```
DECLARE idx, col_cnt, row_cnt, idx_row INT64;
DECLARE col_name, col_flag STRING;
DECLARE cmp_cond,lookup_query, lookup_query_row STRING;
DECLARE col_list ARRAY <STRING>;
DECLARE is_required BOOLEAN;
DECLARE event_names_len, valid_values_len INT64;
DECLARE logic_based_fields STRING; -- this varible is used to hard-coded the rules that are not in the lookup table
DECLARE current_event_date STRING DEFAULT CONCAT("'",CAST(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS STRING),"'");

-- Re-create temp table to get invalid flags fields from base and lookup tables
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_fields_temp` AS
   SELECT
         base.column_name,
         base.column_flag,
         base.required_field_flag,
         base.event_names,
         base.valid_values,
         base.field_name,
         base.__row_number,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY base.column_name ORDER BY base.__row_number) AS field_rank
      FROM
      (
         SELECT 
            bc.column_name,
            vlk.field_name,
            bc.column_flag,
            vlk.required_field_flag,
            vlk.event_names,
            vlk.valid_values,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS __row_number
         FROM 
            (SELECT
               column_name as column_flag,
               SUBSTR (column_name, 1, INSTR(column_name, 'is_invalid')-2) column_name
            FROM
               `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
            WHERE
            table_name = 'st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_test'
            AND column_name LIKE "%is_invalid%"
            ) bc
            INNER JOIN `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_valid_values_lookup_test` vlk
            ON bc.column_name = vlk.field_name
            ORDER BY 1
         ) base
      ORDER BY base.__row_number;

--SELECT * FROM `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_fields_temp`;

-- Set control variables
SET col_cnt = (SELECT COUNT (*) 
               FROM `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_fields_temp`);
SET idx = 1;
SET lookup_query = '';

--build case statements dynamically based on valid values on the lookup table
WHILE idx <= col_cnt DO
   SET (col_flag,col_name) = (
     SELECT AS STRUCT column_flag,column_name 
     FROM `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_fields_temp`
     WHERE __row_number = idx
     );

   SET row_cnt = (SELECT count(*) 
                  FROM `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_fields_temp`
                  WHERE IFNULL(field_name,'') = col_name );

   IF row_cnt = 1 THEN
         --Check if event_names & valid_values arrays are not empty
      SET (event_names_len, valid_values_len, is_required) = (
            SELECT AS STRUCT ARRAY_LENGTH(event_names),ARRAY_LENGTH(valid_values), required_field_flag 
            FROM  `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_fields_temp`
            WHERE field_name = col_name
         );

      --Check event_name + field_name is required + field name has invalid values
      IF (is_required AND event_names_len > 0 AND valid_values_len > 0) THEN
            SET cmp_cond = (
               SELECT CONCAT (",CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(event_name), '^(",LOWER(ARRAY_TO_STRING(event_names,"|")),
               ")') AND (IFNULL(",col_name,",'') = '' OR LOWER(CAST(", LOWER(col_name), " AS STRING)) NOT IN ('", LOWER(ARRAY_TO_STRING (valid_values, "', '")), 
               "')) THEN true ELSE false END AS ",col_flag)
               FROM `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_fields_temp`
               WHERE field_name = col_name
            );
            SET lookup_query = CONCAT(lookup_query, cmp_cond);

         --Check event_name + field_name is required
         ELSEIF (is_required AND event_names_len > 0 AND valid_values_len = 0) THEN
            SET cmp_cond = (
               SELECT CONCAT (",CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(event_name), '^(",LOWER(ARRAY_TO_STRING(event_names,"|")),")') AND IFNULL("
               ,col_name,",'') = '' THEN true ELSE false END AS ",col_flag)
               FROM `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_fields_temp`
               WHERE field_name = col_name
            );
            SET lookup_query = CONCAT(lookup_query, cmp_cond);

         --Check field_name is required      
         ELSEIF (is_required AND event_names_len = 0 AND valid_values_len = 0) THEN
            SET cmp_cond = (
                  SELECT CONCAT (",CASE WHEN IFNULL(", col_name, ",'') = '' THEN true ELSE false END AS ",col_flag)
                  FROM `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_fields_temp`
                  WHERE field_name = col_name
            );
            SET lookup_query = CONCAT(lookup_query, cmp_cond);
      END IF;
   
   -- field_name with multiple rows
   ELSEIF row_cnt > 1 THEN
      SET idx_row = 1;
      SET lookup_query_row = '';
         
      WHILE idx_row <= row_cnt DO
         --Check if event_names & valid_values arrays are not empty
         SET (event_names_len, valid_values_len, is_required) = (
               SELECT AS STRUCT ARRAY_LENGTH(event_names),ARRAY_LENGTH(valid_values), required_field_flag 
               FROM  `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_fields_temp`
               WHERE column_name = col_name and field_rank = idx_row
            );

         --Check event_name + field_name is required + field name has invalid values
         IF (is_required AND event_names_len > 0 AND valid_values_len > 0) THEN
            SET cmp_cond = (
               SELECT CONCAT ("WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(event_name), '^(",LOWER(ARRAY_TO_STRING(event_names,"|")),
               ")') AND (IFNULL(",col_name,",'') = '' OR LOWER(CAST(", LOWER(col_name), " AS STRING)) NOT IN ('", LOWER(ARRAY_TO_STRING (valid_values, "', '")), 
               "')) THEN true ")
               FROM `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_fields_temp`
               WHERE column_name = col_name and field_rank = idx_row
            );
            SET lookup_query_row = CONCAT(lookup_query_row, cmp_cond);
         END IF;
         SET idx_row = idx_row + 1;
      END WHILE;
      SET lookup_query = CONCAT(lookup_query,",CASE ", lookup_query_row, "ELSE false END AS ", col_flag);
      SET idx = idx + row_cnt - 1; -- increment to go to the next field
   
   ELSE
      SET cmp_cond = CONCAT(",NULL AS ", col_flag);
      SET lookup_query = CONCAT(lookup_query, cmp_cond); 
   END IF;
   SET idx = idx + 1; --counter main while loop  
END WHILE;

-- This is a workaround due to BQ's dynamic SQL limitations with nested CASE statements
-- These fields aren't in the valid values lookup table
SET logic_based_fields = (SELECT """
                                 ,CASE 
                                       WHEN LOWER(event_name) LIKE '%video%' AND IFNULL(video_id_channel_id_sports_event_id,'') = '' THEN true 
                                    ELSE false END AS video_id_channel_id_sports_event_id_is_invalid_flag
                                 ,CASE 
                                       WHEN LOWER(event_name) LIKE '%video%' 
                                          AND ((IFNULL(navigation_section,'') ='' AND is_epg IS NOT NULL) 
                                             OR (is_epg IS NULL AND IFNULL(navigation_section,'') <>'') 
                                             OR (is_epg = TRUE AND IFNULL(epg_category,'') = '')) THEN true 
                                    ELSE false END AS client_path_sensitive_properties_is_invalid_flag
                                 ,CASE
                                    WHEN LOWER(event_name) = 'video content playing' 
                                       AND (video_heartbeat_value IS NULL OR video_heartbeat_value > 60 OR video_heartbeat_value <= 0) THEN TRUE
                                    ELSE FALSE END AS video_heartbeat_value_is_invalid_flag
                                 ,CASE WHEN LOWER(event_name) LIKE '%video%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS video_event_flag
                           """);


-- Dynamic SQL to create temp table that will be use to insert into base table and invalid values table
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""
   CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_temp` 
   AS
      SELECT
         event_date
         ,anonymous_id
         ,sl.context_segment_source AS platform_name
         ,os_version
         ,event_id
         ,event_name
         ,event_type
         ,stream_type
         ,session_id
         ,stream_id
         ,ip
         ,navigation_section
         ,is_epg
         ,epg_category
         ,screen_id
         ,screen_title
         ,screen_type
         ,video_content_vertical
         ,video_genres_first
         ,video_id_channel_id_sports_event_id
         ,video_id
         ,channel_id
         ,sports_event_id
         ,video_is_kids
         ,video_player_mode
         ,video_title
         ,video_type
         ,video_heartbeat_value
         ,CASE WHEN event_name = 'Video Content Started' THEN true ELSE false END AS event_is_video_start_flag
         %s
         %s
      FROM (
      SELECT
            context_protocols_source_id,
            DATE(original_timestamp) AS event_date,
            id AS event_id,
            original_event_name AS event_name,
            original_event_type AS event_type,
            context_ip AS ip,
            anonymous_id,
            user_id,
            COALESCE(session_id,
            context_screen_properties_session_id) AS session_id,
            screen_id,
            screen_title,
            screen_type,
            stream_id,
            stream_type,
            video_id,
            video_type,
            video_title,
            video_genres_first,
            video_content_vertical,
            video_is_kids,
            video_player_mode,
            video_heartbeat_value,
            channel_id,
            sports_event_id,
            COALESCE(COALESCE(channel_id,video_id),sports_event_id) AS video_id_channel_id_sports_event_id,
            is_epg,
            epg_category_id,
            epg_category,
            navigation_section,
            context_os_version AS os_version,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY loaded_at DESC) AS __row_number
      FROM
         `st-vix-ott-dev.vix_collapsed_events_dev.master_event`
      WHERE
         DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = %s 
         AND DATE(original_timestamp) = %s
         ) AS mev
      LEFT JOIN
      `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_master_dataset.st_vix_ott_dev_data_segment_lookup_table` sl 
      ON
      mev.context_protocols_source_id = sl.context_protocols_source_id
      WHERE mev.__row_number = 1
""",
logic_based_fields,
lookup_query,
current_event_date,
current_event_date
);

--Insert into the base and invalid values tables
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_temp`) > 0 THEN

   --Delete current event date data to handle multiple runs in the same day
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format(""" 
               DELETE
               FROM
               `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_test`
               WHERE event_date = %s;
   """,
   current_event_date
   );

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""                
               DELETE
               FROM
               `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_invalid_values_test`
               WHERE event_date = %s;
   """,
   current_event_date
   );

   --Insert into base table
   INSERT INTO `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_test`
   (
      event_date,
      anonymous_id,
      platform_name,
      os_version,
      event_id,
      event_name,
      event_type,
      stream_type,
      session_id,
      stream_id,
      ip,
      navigation_section,
      is_epg,
      epg_category,
      screen_id,
      screen_title,
      screen_type,
      video_content_vertical,
      video_genres_first,
      video_id_channel_id_sports_event_id,
      video_id,
      channel_id,
      sports_event_id,
      video_is_kids,
      video_player_mode,
      video_type,
      anonymous_id_is_invalid_flag,
      client_path_sensitive_properties_is_invalid_flag,
      event_is_video_start_flag,
      ip_is_invalid_flag,
      screen_id_is_invalid_flag,
      screen_title_is_invalid_flag,
      screen_type_is_invalid_flag,
      session_id_is_invalid_flag,
      stream_id_is_invalid_flag,
      stream_type_is_invalid_flag,
      video_heartbeat_value,
      video_content_vertical_is_invalid_flag,
      video_genres_first_is_invalid_flag,
      video_heartbeat_value_is_invalid_flag,
      video_id_channel_id_sports_event_id_is_invalid_flag,
      video_is_kids_is_invalid_flag,
      video_player_mode_is_invalid_flag,
      video_type_is_invalid_flag,
      video_event_flag,
      created_datetime
   )
   SELECT 
      event_date,
      anonymous_id,
      platform_name,
      os_version,
      event_id,
      event_name,
      event_type,
      stream_type,
      session_id,
      stream_id,
      ip,
      navigation_section,
      is_epg,
      epg_category,
      screen_id,
      screen_title,
      screen_type,
      video_content_vertical,
      video_genres_first,
      video_id_channel_id_sports_event_id,
      video_id,
      channel_id,
      sports_event_id,
      video_is_kids,
      video_player_mode,
      video_type,
      anonymous_id_is_invalid_flag,
      client_path_sensitive_properties_is_invalid_flag,
      event_is_video_start_flag,
      ip_is_invalid_flag,
      screen_id_is_invalid_flag,
      screen_title_is_invalid_flag,
      screen_type_is_invalid_flag,
      session_id_is_invalid_flag,
      stream_id_is_invalid_flag,
      stream_type_is_invalid_flag,
      video_heartbeat_value,
      video_content_vertical_is_invalid_flag,
      video_genres_first_is_invalid_flag,
      video_heartbeat_value_is_invalid_flag,
      video_id_channel_id_sports_event_id_is_invalid_flag,
      video_is_kids_is_invalid_flag,
      video_player_mode_is_invalid_flag,
      video_type_is_invalid_flag,
      video_event_flag,
      CURRENT_DATETIME()
   FROM `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_temp`;

   --Insert into invalid value_values tables
   INSERT INTO `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_invalid_values_test`
      (
      event_date,
      anonymous_id,
      platform_name,
      os_version,
      event_name,
      event_type,
      event_invalid_values,
      created_datetime  
      )
      WITH cte_invalid
      AS
      (
      SELECT 
            event_date, 
            anonymous_id,       
            platform_name,
            os_version,     
            event_id,       
            event_name,     
            event_type,         
            CASE WHEN video_id_channel_id_sports_event_id_is_invalid_flag THEN video_id_channel_id_sports_event_id ELSE 'valid' END  AS video_id_channel_id_sports_event_id,
            CASE WHEN video_heartbeat_value_is_invalid_flag THEN cast(video_heartbeat_value as string) ELSE 'valid' END AS video_heartbeat_value,
            CASE WHEN ip_is_invalid_flag THEN ip ELSE 'valid' END  AS ip,
            CASE WHEN screen_id_is_invalid_flag THEN screen_id ELSE 'valid' END  AS screen_id,
            CASE WHEN screen_title_is_invalid_flag THEN screen_title ELSE 'valid' END  AS screen_title,
            CASE WHEN screen_type_is_invalid_flag THEN screen_type ELSE 'valid' END  AS screen_type,
            CASE WHEN session_id_is_invalid_flag THEN session_id ELSE 'valid' END  AS session_id,
            CASE WHEN stream_id_is_invalid_flag THEN stream_id ELSE 'valid' END  AS stream_id,
            CASE WHEN stream_type_is_invalid_flag THEN stream_type ELSE 'valid' END  AS stream_type,
            CASE WHEN video_content_vertical_is_invalid_flag THEN video_content_vertical ELSE 'valid' END  AS video_content_vertical,
            CASE WHEN video_genres_first_is_invalid_flag THEN video_genres_first ELSE 'valid' END  AS video_genres_first,
            CASE WHEN video_is_kids_is_invalid_flag THEN video_is_kids ELSE 'valid' END  AS video_is_kids,
            CASE WHEN video_player_mode_is_invalid_flag THEN video_player_mode ELSE 'valid' END  AS video_player_mode,
            CASE WHEN video_type_is_invalid_flag THEN video_type ELSE 'valid' END  AS video_type,
            CASE WHEN client_path_sensitive_properties_is_invalid_flag THEN navigation_section ELSE 'valid' END  AS navigation_section,
            CASE WHEN client_path_sensitive_properties_is_invalid_flag THEN CAST(is_epg AS STRING) ELSE 'valid' END  AS is_epg,
            CASE WHEN client_path_sensitive_properties_is_invalid_flag THEN epg_category ELSE 'valid' END  AS epg_category
      FROM
         `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_temp`
      WHERE 
            video_id_channel_id_sports_event_id_is_invalid_flag 
            OR client_path_sensitive_properties_is_invalid_flag 
            OR video_heartbeat_value_is_invalid_flag 
            OR anonymous_id_is_invalid_flag 
            OR ip_is_invalid_flag 
            OR screen_id_is_invalid_flag 
            OR screen_title_is_invalid_flag 
            OR screen_type_is_invalid_flag 
            OR session_id_is_invalid_flag 
            OR stream_id_is_invalid_flag 
            OR stream_type_is_invalid_flag 
            OR video_content_vertical_is_invalid_flag 
            OR video_genres_first_is_invalid_flag 
            OR video_is_kids_is_invalid_flag 
            OR video_player_mode_is_invalid_flag 
            OR video_type_is_invalid_flag

      ),
      cte_invalid_agg
      AS
      (SELECT 
            event_date, 
            anonymous_id,       
            platform_name,
            os_version,             
            event_name,     
            event_type,
            event_id,
         ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(field_name,invalid_field_value)) AS invalid_field_value,
      FROM
      (
         SELECT
            *
         FROM 
         cte_invalid
      ) sl
      UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS
      (
         invalid_field_value FOR field_name IN (video_id_channel_id_sports_event_id,
                                                video_heartbeat_value,
                                                ip,
                                                screen_id,
                                                screen_title,
                                                screen_type,
                                                session_id,
                                                stream_id,
                                                stream_type,
                                                video_content_vertical,
                                                video_genres_first,
                                                video_is_kids,
                                                video_player_mode,
                                                video_type,
                                                navigation_section,
                                                is_epg,
                                                epg_category
                                                )
      
      )
      WHERE IFNULL(invalid_field_value,'') <> 'valid'
      GROUP BY       
            event_date, 
            anonymous_id,       
            platform_name,
            os_version,             
            event_name,     
            event_type,
            event_id
      )

      SELECT 
            event_date, 
            anonymous_id,       
            platform_name,
            os_version,             
            event_name,     
            event_type,
            ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(event_id, invalid_field_value)) AS event_invalid_values,
            CURRENT_DATETIME()
      FROM cte_invalid_agg
      GROUP BY
            event_date, 
            anonymous_id,       
            platform_name,
            os_version,             
            event_name,     
            event_type;

   --Drop temp tables
   DROP TABLE `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_temp`;
   DROP TABLE `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_fields_temp`;
      
END IF
```

The DAG which I have created is :-

```
import datetime
import os
import logging
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryInsertJobOperator
from composer_plugins import get_query_content


# Environments variables
event_collection_project_id = os.environ["EVENT_COLLECTION_PROJECT_ID"]
sql_scripts_folder = os.environ["SQL_SCRIPTS_FOLDER"]
QA_CHECK_QUERY= "DMLs/data_qa_checks/DQ_check_base_table_new.sql"


yesterday = datetime.datetime.combine(
    datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(1), datetime.datetime.min.time()
)

insert_data_from_sql_file = get_query_content(
    sql_scripts_folder,QA_CHECK_QUERY
)

logging.info(f"query: {insert_data_from_sql_file}")

default_dag_args = {
    # Setting start date as yesterday starts the DAG immediately when it is
    # detected in the Cloud Storage bucket.
    "start_date": yesterday,
    # To email on failure or retry set 'email' arg to your email and enable
    # emailing here.
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    # If a task fails, retry it once after waiting at least what's specified in retry_delay
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": datetime.timedelta(seconds=10),
    "project_id": event_collection_project_id,
}

with DAG(
        dag_id="data_qa_checks",
        schedule_interval=None,
        default_args=default_dag_args,
) as dag:

    # call the query that will insert the data from sql file and it will do the operations which are mentioned in the query
    DQ_dml = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id="DQ_dml",
        job_id="{{ ts_nodash }}-DQ_dml",
        configuration={
            "query": {
                "query": insert_data_from_sql_file,
                "useLegacySql": "False",
            },
        },
        dag=dag,
    )
```

Image which shows my DAG got triggered but now it's failing :-
[image]

Error :-

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Query error: No matching signature for function ARRAY_LENGTH for argument types: STRING. Supported signature: ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY) at [70:30]

Location: US
Job ID: 20220617T045920-DQ_dml_6a48df549274df9c428e14be75b52d31

[2022-06-17 04:59:49,628] {taskinstance.py:1511} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=data_qa_checks, task_id=DQ_dml, execution_date=20220617T045920, start_date=20220617T045943, end_date=20220617T045949
[2022-06-17 04:59:49,838] {local_task_job.py:151} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-06-17 04:59:49,890] {local_task_job.py:261} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

There was no error when it was getting triggered :-
[image]

Can someone please help me for the same.

Comment: `google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Query error: No matching signature for function ARRAY_LENGTH for argument types: STRING. Supported signature: ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY) at [70:30]` This means you are passing a string in ARRAY_LENGTH instead of an array. Convert String into a list of string and try to execute it again.

Comment: Check if event_names or valid_values getting a single string value due to some case condition.
I would suggest printing these both and checking types when the dag fails.

Comment: Check the datatypes of columns in case of joins. Both should be same

Comment: SELECT AS STRUCT ARRAY_LENGTH(event_names),ARRAY_LENGTH(valid_values)

this line in your sql file is causing issue and either of the event_names or valid_values are coming as string and causing this exception. So a good place to check how these values are coming is where you create this table:

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `st-vix-ott-dev.st_vix_ott_dev_us_data_dq_quality_checks.st_vix_ott_dev_dq_monitoring_base_fields_temp`